# Programming a Raspberry over SSH or Wifi?

Tags: wifi, ssh, connection, openssh

So I am planning to host a discord bot on a raspberry pi zero w and I do have a spare monitor( for the programming part), but the monitor wouldn't work when I plug it in and I also don't have one of those mouse+keyboard things, so I have done a bit of research and I have seen many headless setups on youtube, but how do I program it, can I do it with a USB connected to my mac or over wifi, I am open to any suggestions thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily program your `Raspberry Pi Zero W` via SSH. Should be configured Wi-Fi connection and SSH to be enabled.

Follow the next steps:

1. Go to Raspiconfig, just type in terminal:
   `sudo raspi-config`
   [image]
2. choose Interfacing Options and set SSH enable. This will help to connect to Raspberry Pi via SSH.
3. After that, go back and go to Network Options and choose Wi-Fi. Fill name and password of the Wi-Fi. `SSID` - name of your Wi-Fi, `Password` - password to it.
4. To be sure, that all configuration work as expected - reboot your Raspberry

`sudo reboot`

5. Next, need to understand the ip address of the Raspberry to connect to. For this, you should write:
   `sudo ifconfig`
   and you will see. In this picture ip-address is `192.168.0.104`
   [image]
6. Connect via SSH to pi@192.168.0.104.

If you have any questions - see full description [here](https://github.com/romankh3/raspberrypi-home-ecosystem/blob/master/BASE_CONFIGURATION.md#turn-on-raspberry-and-set-wi-fi-connection).

Comment: Nice answer. But you may not need the IP address as `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` should work out of the box on Mac and GNU/Linux.

Comment: Really? I haven't used it before. Can it be used in the case when I have more than one raspberry?

Comment: Please don't use images for text output. Instead paste the text direct into the answer.

Comment: @Ingo, ok, it's not a problem.

Comment: No, but if you change the Pi's hostname the part between `@` and `.local` will change to match so you can just rename your Pi's. It can be persuaded to work on Windows as well but you need to make it aware of mDNS/Bonjour/ZeroConf stuff first.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily program a Raspberry Pi over SSH. I guess you've already seen in headless setups how to configure your RPi to connect to your WiFi network and enable SSH. If not, here is a quick how-to:

#### Setup headless RPi

Add an empty `ssh` file in `/boot/` directory

Inside the `rootfs` partition, edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file so that it looks like this

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="YourWiFiSSID"
    psk="yourSecretWiFipassword"
}
```

Here's the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) on how to setup WiFi.

You can connect to your RPi from your mac over an SSH session. Once inside, in the terminal you can use a text editor (nano is the default one but you could download something else. I like vim.) to write your programs. Then you can run them in your SSH terminal.

Here's a quick [overview of SSH](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/unix.md).