# Wifi Connectivity -- Pi 3 Model B

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wpa

I have recently been unable to connect to wifi with my raspberry pi 3 (model B). I have tried a number of solutions to no avail.

The networks button on the upper banner says "connection to dhcpcd lost" or "no wireless interfaces found".

However, when I try `iwlist wlan0 scan` to search for networks, I can see dozens of wifi networks, including my own. I then go to `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and add my network and password at the bottom of the file. Even following a reboot I have no networks displaying on the upper bar and no wifi connection.

How come in the terminal my raspberry pi recognizes networks, but not in the GUI? How can I resolve this problem to be able to connect?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What Operating System are you running?

Comment: Are you using an adequate power supply? The first thing to fail if the power supply is weak & weedy is the on-board WiFi. What do you get from `iwlist scan` can you see your AP's SSID?

Comment: @Dougie This was my presumption. I can see the SSID. I just ordered an adequate power supply to test that out as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of editing the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, try running `raspi-config` (or `sudo raspi-config`) in terminal and choose the option to setup your WiFi connection.

My guess here is that you haven't specified your country yet, which is something you need to add to your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file. Once you run `raspi-config` to configure your network connection, if you haven't done it it, you will be prompted to specify your country.

In the end, your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file should look something like this:

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="YourWiFiSSID"
    psk="yourSecretWiFipassword"
}
```

#### If the previous doesn't work, then try this

Type `ifconfig` or `ip a` to see which network interfaces are enabled. In your case, you're probably looking for `wlan0`.

You can try to enable all wireless devices by running `rfkill unblock all`.

Check for any error messages by typing `dmesg` or look into the `/var/log/syslog` file.

Comment: Unfortunately I have attempted this without success. Being in the US I have changed the country code in your code above to `US` as well as in `raspi-config`

Comment: @a.powell, what Operating System are you running?

Comment: I'm using Raspian (Linux) @David

Comment: @a.powell, some things you can try (in case you haven't) are typing `dmesg` in your terminal to see if there are any errors related to your network devices. Similarly, you can use `vim` or `nano` to check the `/var/log/syslog` file and try to find any errors related to configuring your network. I will update my answer to provide more options to diagnose your problem.

Comment: when I run `dmesg` there is one line that says: `IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready`. Could this be the source of my problem?

Comment: Additionally, when I try `ifconfig` I get this line: `wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500`

Comment: @a.powell, can you `ping` other computers in your network? If so, I suspect you're facing a `DHCP` issue.

Comment: @a.powell, if you haven't tried it yet, restart your DHCP client with `sudo service dhcpcd restart` or `systemctl restart dhcpcd.service`

Answer (score 0):

The full answer you can find in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95697/100391) .

You can configure your Wi-Fi connection via **raspi-config**.

Follow next steps:

1. Go to Raspiconfig, just type in terminal: `$ sudo raspi-config`

And configuration window will open and looks like the picture below: 
[image]
2. Go to `Network Options` and choose `Wi-Fi`.

3. Fill name and password of the Wi-Fi. `SSID` - name of your Wi-Fi, `Password` - password to it.
4. To be sure, that all configuration work as expected - reboot your Raspberry `sudo reboot`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will re-try this but have done so multiple times including the reboot with no success

Comment: The last chance is to save important data and flash the new OS on microSD.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct answer has already been given, but it may be that there's something else going on. Have you looked into the system log to see if there's any useful information there? run journalctl and then scroll through looking for dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant log entries.